# Iterating through const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch>& touch-Cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to use multitouch and wrote the required events and listeners.Now I want to get touched sprite,for that,I should get location of touched point but I don't know how get that into below code:

```
void Break::onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<Touch*>& touch, Event* event)
{
    What should I write here for getting touched sprite?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you used scene graph priority when adding the listener

event->target() will give you the sprite

Answer (score 0):

If your scene is listening to the event, then event->target() would give you the base node, not the one touched. In that case you would need some form of touch detection (either by checking rects, or by performing radius<=distance check, or by a more sophisticated algorithm - it all depends on your situation).

If your objects are listening for the events then you can use event->target(), but you still need some form of collision detection, so that touch-event system would know wether the touch is successful, or not. As far as I am aware, cocos doesn't perform those checks for you.
Just an example (your logic may differ - for example you may consider touch to be touching your object if at least one of the touches collides with it's bounding box or whatnot):

```
void Break::onTouchesBegan(const std::vector<Touch*>& touch, Event* event)
{
    //If at least one touch doesn't touch the object - then there is no touch
    for(auto& t : touch){
        if(!COLLISION_CHECK){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    //OR
    //If at least one touch touches the object, then there is a touch
    for(auto& t : touch){
        if(COLLISION_CHECK){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```